# Why doesn't $\pm a = \pm b \implies -a = b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem arises from $a^2=b^2$. Since each variables could be positive or negative it feels like all permutations should be valid equalities?

Comment: You're asking if $a^2=b^2\implies a=-b$? What if $a=b=3$?

Comment: how would you go about arguing that $a^2=b^2$ implies $-a=b$???

Comment: $a^2 = b^2 \Rightarrow a^2 - b^2 = 0 \Rightarrow (a-b)(a+b) = 0 \Rightarrow a = b \text{ or } a = -b$.

At least one of those last statements is necessarily true. But not necessarily one of them in particular.

Comment: I think the confusion might be over what the symbol for "plus or minus" means. I like to think of this as a set - that these expressions say $\{a, -a \} = \{b, -b \}$as sets.

Comment: If $a^2=b^2$, then *either* $a=b$ *or* $a=-b$.

Comment: @SimonS Are you saying that “either $0=0$ or $0=0$” is false? It's just the usual mathematical “or”.

Comment: My mistake. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem lies in looking at $\pm a$ as some sort of object. $\pm$ is just a shorthand used. In reality, when you solve $a^2=b^2$, you say that $a$ and $b$ must have the same value squared, and that gives you your four solution pairs. There is no fundamental reason why a $\pm$ sign is used in equations like this. You just use it if the actual reasoning behind solving the equation permits it.

Comment: Maybe the notation is the confusing bit here. This makes sense to me.

Comment: Teaching students something like $x^2=4\implies x=\pm2$ opens the way to $x^2\le 4\implies x\le\pm2$, not only to misunderstanding like the OP's.

Answer (score 2):

$$\pm a=\pm b\iff +a=+b\lor-a=+b\lor+a=-b\lor-a=-b$$
which can be simplified as
$$\pm a=\pm b\iff a=b\lor-a=b$$
(where $\lor$ means "or")

Comment: Sometimes (but not here) it is understood that any two $\pm$-signs in an equation have the same sign (and that a $\mp$-sign has the opposite sign). For instance in $(a \pm b)^2 = a^2 \pm 2ab + b^2$.

Comment: @user133281: as you say, not here.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer comes from the number line. Plainly, A does not equal -A ( they are opposite values). Yet, squaring real numbers always results in a positive number. Therefore while $(-a)^2=(+a)^2$ the roots may be either equal OR opposite. This prevents your paradoxical conclusion. Thus  the correct conclusion must be -a=-b and +a=+b.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the $\pm$ symbol is that it takes the same value ($+$ or $-$) anywhere it is used in one expression. Conversely, the $\mp$ sign is used for values that are $+$ when $\pm$ is $-$ and vice versa. So, for example,

$ \pm a \pm b $ can be either $a+b$ or $-a-b$, and

$ \pm a \mp b $ means either $-a+b$ or $a-b$.

(Note: if you only need one of them, it is conventional to use $\pm$.)

If you want to characterise the solutions to $a^2=b^2$, you can say $a=\pm b$, $a=\mp b$, or $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b \rvert$.

**Edit:** the other thing to point out is that $a=-b \iff -a=b$, I suppose, so you cover all options with "$a=b$ or $a=-b$".